# Laravel: generate a list of month of a mysql date field

Tags: date, laravel, eloquent

I want to generate with Laravel/Eloquent a list of months from a date field in a MySQL table.

How can I group the query and generate a list of the months?

The list is intended for a select field for later filtering entries per month.

```
id  user_id garage_id   date            time
1   1       23          2015-09-11      02:23:00
5   1       17          2015-09-07      03:36:00
6   1       136         2015-08-02      23:22:00
7   1       83          2015-08-13      14:56:00
8   1       3           2015-07-16      14:58:00
9   1       67          2015-07-09      10:51:00
```

Thanks
Mirko

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: sorry, nothing, my brain is freezing, i have no plan for solve the problem at the moment :/

Comment: Then at least show the table structure with some sample data, and an example of the expected result data structure, because so far your question is a little too broad.

Comment: You should try first: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent
Then, if you have any doubt, we'll be happy to help you.

Comment: there are some sample data,
i want a list with the month: july, august, september

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupBy()` on the DB query, which essentially gives you a list of unique values.

```
$unqiue_dates = DB::table('your_table')
    ->where('some_condition','=','if you like')
    ->groupBy('created_at') // or whatever date field
    ->get();
```

Then, once you've passed this data onto a Laravel blade template you could iterate through them like:

```
<select>
@foreach ($unique_dates as $date)
    <option>{{ date('F', strtotime($date)) }}</option>
@endforeach
<select>
```

Using 'F' as the format character gives a full textual representation e.g. January.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution outside of Laravel and Eloquent:

SELECT MONTHNAME(date) as month FROM cp_dbcarsharing GROUP BY MONTH(date)

Now i tweak it for my situation ;)

Thanks